# Where to initialize variables in an Angular 4 component - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an Angular 4 component with a Boolean variable. The initial value is depending on an input stream.

TypeScript demands me to declare the variable like in the example below. Without it this.isLoading will trigger an error.

At this point I don't know it's value yet so I just declare it without assigning a variable.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() someStream$;
  isLoading: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    someStream.subscribe((someData) => {
      // Code to determine the value for isLoading
      this.isLoading = true; 
    });
  }
}
```

Later when I do know the value I'll set it to either true or false. But then 'ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError' kicks in.

What it's the 'correct way' to set these kinds of 'default' values.

Comment: try ngOnChages() life cycle instead of ngOnInit(), it might solve your problem.

Comment: When and where you call next on someStream ?

Comment: @MohamedGara in the same onInit block is some logic that checks URL parameters. If all required parameters are there it starts an http call and sets isLoading.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that isLoading is your flag to know if the request is completed.
What I did in this scenario was to initialize loading as false:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() someStream$;
  // Initialized as false.
  isLoading: boolean = false;

  ...
}
```

If isLoading flag has more logic, I would change the way you interact with the component and change the @Input() to someData directly, and handle the async logic in it's parent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work when isLoading evaluates to true within 'the same tick' in ngOnInit I am getting the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. I'm afraid that moving the variable up to the parent just moves the issue to another component.

Comment: Kinda weird, because I have exactly the same code you have and it's not throwing any error. Just to be sure, is your subscription being triggered only once? Maybe the observable is sending new values during the same cycle.